# what is wrong with the below code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, geolocation

```
string str = "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
                 "var lat=lon=-1;" +
                 "getLocation();" +
             "function getLocation() {" +
                 "if (navigator.geolocation) {" +
                     "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);" +
                 "}" +
              "}" +
             "function showPosition(position) {" +
                 "lat=position.coords.latitude;" +
                 "lon=position.coords.longitude;" +
                 "document.getElementById('<%=ltrLat.ClientID%>').innerHTML=lat;"+
                 "document.getElementById('<%=ltrLon.ClientID%>').innerHTML= lon;"+
                 "var x= document.getElementById('<%=ltrLat.ClientID%>').innerHTML;"+
                 "var y= document.getElementById('<%=ltrLon.ClientID%>').innerHTML;" +
                 "alert('lat='+x+'lon='+ y);" +
             "}" +
             "</script>";
              ClientScriptManager cs = this.ClientScript;
              cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"xyz", str);
```

ltrLat and ltrLon are asp label on client side.
moreover the labels are not displayed
I do not get the alert.

Comment: string s is never used

Comment: Note: `<%= ... %>` is only recognized within an `.aspx` file as part of the rendering process. It won't be substituted within a string literal or `.cs` file.

Answer (score 0):

i also tried something like this but what i got was that .net strings wont let you write scripts so i would suggest you to embed the script in .aspx and define global variables in .cs then in the script use these variables as

```
<script>    
var x= <%= globalXInCS %>
</script>
```

Comment: The main thing that i want to do here is run the script from the server side using Register startup script and then read the coordinates in the script on the server.

Comment: you want to get the location of server or client?

Comment: I want to get client device location using geolocation api which i am using in the above script. I followed your way and embedded the script in .aspx and called the getLocation function from server. It is working. The lat and lon are the coordinates. But i am not able to read these values on the server side.

Comment: you want the latitude or longitude on server side? than you have two ways temporarily store the latitude and longitude in some textboxes via jquery and when thing is confirmed, get the value of the textboxes..

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in .aspx if you want to use Ajax
keep in mind you have to create a webmethod to handle ajax Requests  in .cs file
**.aspx**

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (evt) {

```
                    var lati = evt.latLng.lat();
                    var longi = evt.latLng.lng();
                    var data1 = JSON.stringify({ latitude: lati, longitude: longi, locationId: this.id });

                    Updatelocations(data1);
                });


 function Updatelocations(data1) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: window.location.pathname + '/UpdateLoc',
                data: data1,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                    alert("Location Updated..!");
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                    alert(data1);
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

**.cs**

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void UpdateLoc(double latitude, double longitude, long locationId)
    {
        double lti = Convert.ToDouble(latitude);
        double lngi = Convert.ToDouble(longitude);
        long locationid= Convert.ToInt64(locationId);
        DACLocation.UpdateLocation(lti, lngi, locationId);
    }
```

I hope you will understand well